# Is Websocket good solution for realtime GPS taxi driver application?

Tags: node.js, flutter, websocket, redis

I am working on an online taxi project

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Backend | Nodejs |
| Main Database | Postgresql |
| mobile application | flutter |

One of the parts that has created a lot of challenges is the online location of the taxi driver, which must be available on the admin panel and the passenger can see the location of the taxi in realtime.

I read a lot of documentation that we can store the taxi location data in the Redis database and then the user can read it.
And that I can establish online communication with websocket

The question is, is web socket the best solution?
Because the web socket on the servers has a connection limit And I want to know what is the best solution for this issue? Should I continue the web socket or can I use another technology?

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are a good option when your connection is point-to-point. WebSocket is designed for a full-duplex/bidirectional communication channel. In your scenario, WebSocket is a better option than others.

You can also use Firebase. Firebase provides a stream of data and real-time update feature Firebase is easy to setup and its pricing plan is reliable.

Setting up websockets is a tedious task at the beginner level, there are many SDKs available for real-time data updates, and you can easily integrate them into your application.

When your app reaches a certain level of audience and other SDKs drain your money you can start thinking about migrating to WebSocket otherwise third-party SDKs are a good option for the MVP stage in my opinion.